# what is best way to test if an array of items are within a predefined array

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

By giving an array of string, I would like to test if each element in the array is contained in the predefined array of string.

For example:

```
var a = new[] { "test1", "test2" };

var b = new[] { "test1", "test4" };

var c = new[] { "test1", "test3", "test1", "test3" };

var predefined = new[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
```

variable a and c will return true, b will return false.

What is the most efficient way of C# code?

Comment: How large is the collection you expect to be testing against?

Comment: If it's a possibility to change the type of `predifend` into `var predefined = new HashSet<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3", };`, then you might get better performance. There's an `IsSupersetOf` method on `HashSet<>` that you can use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does ordering matter for you? If not, I'd just use LINQ:

```
if (!a.Except(predefined).Any())
{
    // predefined contains every element of a
    // (Way to read this: there is no element of a which isn't also in predefined)
}
```

That will generally be O(N + M) as opposed to the `All`...`Contains` solution which is O(N * M). That doesn't state the *absolute* performance, of course. If you're using small collections, the `All`...`Contains` may actually be faster. As the collections involved grow larger, this is more likely to be faster.

EDIT: As noted in comments, if you can create a `HashSet<T>` from `predefined` and reuse it, it can be more efficient... and actually far more readable too:

```
var predefinedSet = new HashSet<string>(predefined);
...

if (predefinedSet.IsSupersetOf(a))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for noting big O performance notation for two proposed solutions

Comment: If you make predefined a HashSet, doesn't `All` ... `Contains` become O(N)?

Comment: definitely better than my answer.. I just think the variables names should be reversed according to the question

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a.Except(predefined)`?

Comment: @MattW: Yes, but then it also becomes effectively `Except`, which will do that for you... and the solution presented uses arrays, not sets.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: Yup, fixed - including the comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet If predefined is truly predefined, don't you want to make it into a HashSet just once instead of every call, though?

Comment: @MattW: Yes, you could do so. It's hard to tell a great amount from the question, to be honest.

Comment: If I could use a HashSet to get to All/Contains, I probably would elect to do so. It's mentally a direct path to understanding, whereas the perfectly appropriate "!first.Except(second).Any()" takes more thought to understand. *How much* more is, of course, different for each reader.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Yup, definitely agree on that. Will add more detail around that.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Actually, with `HashSet<T>` it gets even better... use `IsSupersetOf`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was not aware of the IsSupersetOf and IsSubsetOf methods on HashSet<T>. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if the most efficient but the most easy to read and standard code would be

```
arrayToCheck.All(a => predefined.Contains(a))
```